# Blurry links in Node Editor

Tags: node-editor, blur

i'm with this issue on Node Editor. This is probably a repeated question here, but I couldn't find. Sometimes, and I don't know the exact reason, the links of the Node Editor gets blurry and only gets back normal when I reset Blender, does anyone knows why?

[image]

Comment: That definitely looks like a bug, or perhaps a hardware incompatibility. What are your system specs?

Comment: Xeon E5506 2.13 GHz, 12GB RAM, Radeon HD 4770, Windows 64 bit